# How to show "Iterator" at UML class diagram in VisualStudio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, uml

Is there any way to mark operation in UML diagram as iterator?
My purpose is, to get iterator in generated from UML diagram code.

Comment: Iterator is NOT an operation, but an object.

Answer (score 0):

What you can always do in such cases is to stereotype it:

[image]