# How to show(reflect) “property” at UML class diagram in VisualStudio? (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, uml

My purpose is, to get 'property' in generated from UML diagram code. Is there any way to mark operation in UML diagram as "property" that will say VisualStudio to generate it in code as property (not method)?

Answer (score 3):

You do that the same way as in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34391415/how-to-show-iterator-at-uml-class-diagram-in-visualstudio) by stereotyping the method:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**'Stereotype' that marks class attribute as class property** in VisualStudio 2015 looks like:

[image]

I use VisualStudio 2015. I didn't fined opportunity to mark 'class property' manually by 'stereotype' in class frame (I mean,that I didn't fined opportunity to print 'stereotype' by hand in 'class frame').

**You can setup 'stereotypes' in 'Property tab'**(Maybe there is another way to do it in Visual Studio, but I didn't find it):

1) *Create class 'attribute(field)' in 'class frame' using class context menu*.

2) *Select created attribute in class frame. Use context menu to get 'property' menu-item.*

3) *Choose 'stereotype' item in opened 'property tab'. Select needed value from combo-box.*

[image]